# unexpected character after line continuation character in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

This is my code for removing vowels from given string.My code shows unexpected character after line continuation character in if statement condition?can anyone help

```
def anti_vowel(text):
r=len(text)
new=[]
for i in range(0,r):
if lower.text[i]!='a' and lower.text[i]!='e'
    and lower.text[i]!='i' and  lower.text[i]!='o' and lower.text[i]!='u':
    new.append(text[i])
print " ".join(new)`
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Any example input and output of the function?

Comment: anti_vowel("Hey You!") should return "Hy Y!"  @Marcin

Comment: I would try and avoid using "new" - just for cynical purposes. Why don't you use "new_Words"

Comment: Fix your indentation first! It's wrong

Comment: First of all, you need to indent your code. Then use functions properly. The `lower.text[i]` and the similar expressions are incorrect; You need to apply the `lower()` statement _after_ the string.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your function to use set and list comprehension:

```
def anti_vowel(text):            
    vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'i'}
    new = [a_letter for a_letter in text if a_letter not in vowels]                    
    return "".join(new)    

print(anti_vowel("Hey You!"))
#prints: Hy Yu!
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply tried to prove your work using this - Is that what you had in mind?

```
text="The brown fox quickly jumped over the lazy dog"
list_of_vow = ['a','e','i','o','u']
new_word = text;

for x in list_of_vow:
    new_word = new_word.replace(x,'')
print(new_word)
```